# [mui-x][DateTimePicker][v6] How to set onChange and onBlur with 3rd party form library?

Tags: material-ui, datetimepicker

Code example with Formik (not reproducible): https://stackblitz.com/edit/next-typescript-ffn4ta?file=components/CustomDateTimePicker.tsx

#### Description

Well, mui-x DateTimePicker v5 used to provide us onBlur or onChange with event, so that we can communicate with 3rd party library (like doing `onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}` or so).

But this time, we have values like date or string instead of event.

How do I manage to it work with Formik (or something else)?

#### Expected result

I am expecting DateTimePicker to work with Formik (also other 3rd part libs)

Thus, we can use like:

```
<DateTimePicker
  value={value}
  onChange={newValue => onChange(new ChangeEvent(...))}
  onBlur={() => onBlur(new FocusEvent('blur'))}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this isn't answering your question, but you're able to add `onFocus` and `onBlur` functionality to date picker with the following! Docs [here](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#slots) under the `textField` slot prop.

```
const [isDateFieldFocused, setDateFieldFocused] = useState(false);

const handleDateFieldFocus = () => {
   setDateFieldFocused(true);
};

const handleDateFieldBlur = () => {
   setDateFieldFocused(false);
};

<StyledDatePicker
    value={value}
    onChange={(newValue: any) => onChange(newValue)}
    slotProps={{
        textField: {
            onFocus: handleDateFieldFocus,
            onBlur: handleDateFieldBlur,
        },
    }}
/>
```